# Why different behaviour of same code by different compilers?

Tags: c

This is code written by me where I have to print a single integer denoting the minimum possible capacity of a tram (0 is allowed). It's a problem from codeforces. The answer in CodeBlocks is showing 6 (the right answer) but in codeforces compiler I'm getting another output.

Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n, i, j, max = 0, sum = 0;
  int pssnger_left;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int a[n][2];

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &a[i][j]); // declaring the value of array
    }
  }
  pssnger_left = a[0][0] + a[0][1];

  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    sum = pssnger_left - a[i][0];
    sum = sum + a[i][i];
    pssnger_left = sum;

    if (max < sum)
      max = sum;
  }
  printf("%d", max);
}
```

Input:

```
4
0 3
2 5
4 2
4 0
```

Output:

```
4221555
```

Answer:

```
6
Checker Log
wrong answer expected 6, found 4221555
```

Here is the link of the problem: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/116/A

Comment: Different compiler, different answer, 99% UB. Let's see whether I can find it.

Comment: Here it is `a[i][i];` for any `i` > 1 that is not what you want it to be and for most high `i` it illegally accesses beyond `a` -> Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `sum = sum + a[i][i];` -> `sum = sum + a[i][1];`

Comment: You need to learn how to catch boring typo bugs like this yourself by using a debugger. If you single-step through this program you'll surely notice `sum` going haywire at the line `sum = sum + a[i][i];`.

Comment: There is also no need to use an array as you can do the calculation each time a line of numbers is read.

Answer (score 3):

Different compiler, different answer, 99% of the cases is explained by Undefined Behaviour, UB.

In the shown code here it is `a[i][i];`.
For any `i` > 1 that is not what you want it to be
and for most high `i` it illegally accesses beyond `a`.

-> Undefined Behaviour.

A hint on how I spotted this:
Whenever I see `[i][i]`, actually whenever I see `[same][same]`,
I think "diagonal in a square". And in your code I immediatly thought "What square?", because when seeing `int a[n][2];` I thought "Long narrow table." and got a conflict of shapes there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not basically with the compiler.
You are doing
sum = sum + a[i][i];
but you have declared a 2D array of n x 2 i.e. int a[n][2]

see in some compilers it shows out of bound because you are accessing an element which is not there in the array
and in compilers it just loops in the already existing array for ex if your array has 5 elements and you are trying to access 6th element then it will go back to 1st index,
so this might be whats happening here.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined. It doesn't have to "show out of bound" nor to "loops in the already existing array". More likely it will dutifully read arbitrary and/or uninitialised memory and get undefined garbage back. But there's not much point in trying to predict how it fails.